# When the changes in ApplicationInsights.config apply?

Tags: azure-application-insights

If i edit applicationInsights.config file on working application (or replace whole file), when the changes apply?

Does it happen immediately or I have to restart my application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ApplicationInsights.config` file contains names of classes to load, etc, so it is only read on startup of the app.

You'll need to restart your app pick up any changes.